# What permissions settings does push-to-deploy require?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, file-permissions

The title is general, but I have more specific questions.  I am deep in a permissions nightmare trying to set up a "push-to-deploy" system using Git.

From my local machine, I push by SSH to the server (Ubuntu 14.04).  I have the server set up as the remote

```
git remote add development devuser@development.server:/home/dummyuser/bare/repo.git
```

This bare repository is within the home folder of a dummy user `dummyuser` that we use to handle deployment tasks.  `devuser` is my own account on the development server.

I have a `post-receive` hook set up within the remote repository (`development.server:/home/dummyuser/bare/repo.git/hooks/post-receive`) that's intended to deploy files via `git checkout` to a web server directory on the same server, call it `webfolder/`.  That folder currently has permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x dummyuser www-data webfolder/
```

where `www-data` is the group associated with the Apache user.

If I have the `post-receive` hook script use the command

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/webfolder --git-dir=/home/dummyuser/bare/repo.git checkout -f
```

I get errors that it can't write to `webfolder/`, which is predictable since I assume the script is running as me (`devuser`) since I did the instigating push via SSH, and `devuser` doesn't have any permissions on `webfolder/`.

However, if I change the script to act as `dummyuser`,

```
sudo -u dummyuser git --work-tree=/var/www/webfolder --git-dir=/home/dummyuser/bare/repo.git checkout -f
```

just to see what happens, I have the error

```
warning: unable to access '/home/devuser/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
```

There's a couple of things I don't understand about this:

1) Neither `/home/devuser/.config/` nor `/home/dummyuser/.config/` exist.  That's fine, but if Git needs to access a `.config/` folder, why wasn't it complaining before when I was setting up bare repos and executing hooks as `devuser`?

2) Now that I'm trying to act as `dummyuser`, why is Git looking in `~devuser/` for a `.config/` folder?  Why isn't it looking in `~dummyuser/?`

I've been working on this tiny slice of one single problem in the maddening shitshow that is "using Git" for coming up on four hours now, and my brain is fuzzy, so please use small words.

Comment: @Liam Yes, Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I'm mostly convinced that "push to deploy" is a bad strategy. Or more precisely, using Git as a deployment tool is just wrong. There's nothing wrong with using Git to replicate repositories, but it's a terrible deployment tool. But you may be stuck with it...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is something involving `sudo -u dummyuser` not setting the environment variables that Git expects.  If I add `HOME=/home/dummyuser` to the `post-receive` hook, the deployment works as expected.

If anyone can provide more details about what's happening or a better solution, write it as an answer and I'll accept it.  Couple of notes:

- `dummyuser` doesn't have a login, so using `sudo -iu dummyuser` in the `post-receive` script won't work
- After setting `HOME=/home/dummyuser` manually and successfully executing the script, I find that `echo $HOME` from the terminal returns `/home/devuser`, so there's no permanent change to `$HOME`
- After successfully executing the hook script, neither `~devuser/` nor `~dummyuser/` nor `/root/` have a `.config/` folder.  So... I still have no idea why Git was hung up on it.

Answer (score 0):

Git expects a `.config` folder in the user's home directory. If `$HOME` isn't set correctly, e.g. if it points to a different user's home, Git will try to access `$HOME/.config`, not knowing that it actually doesn't even exist. However, since the user, and thus Git, doesn't have access to that `$HOME`, you will receive an error saying `Permission denied`.

To test that, try to run as `dummyuser`:

```
[ -d /home/devuser/.config ] && echo '.config exists!'
```

You're trying to test if the directory `/home/devuser/.config` exists. However, since you don't have the needed permissions, you get `Permission denied`, and you still don't know whether the directory exists or not.

Instead of setting `$HOME` manually, you could possibly use `-H` or `--set-home`:

```
sudo -Hu dummyuser git --work-tree=/var/www/webfolder --git-dir=/home/dummyuser/bare/repo.git checkout -f
```